# How are Autocallables modelled?

Tags: modeling, heston, barrier, sabr, black-scholes-merton

What models are used to price autocallables ? Should we talk about Heston/SABR models which talking about this topic ? Any reference link is welcome.

Comment: Depends on the structure, local stochastic volatility usually, but if it is on an index/portfolio then you need to include some modelling of correlation. See here: https://www.risk.net/our-take/6348336/calling-out-autocallable-pricing